# How to check results of wget/urllib2 in Python?

Tags: python, urllib2, wget

I am brand new to Python and am trying to write a monitor to determine whether a Java web app (WAR file) running on `localhost` (hosted by Apache Tomcat) is running or not. I had earlier devised a script that ran:

```
ps -aef | grep myWebApp
```

And inspected the results of the `grep` to see if any process IDs came back in those results.

But it turns out that the host OS only sees the Tomcat process, not any web apps Tomcat is hosting. I next tried to see if Tomcat came with any kind of CLI that I could hit from the terminal, and it looks like the answer is no.

Now, I'm thinking of using `wget` or maybe even `urllib2` to determine if my web app is running by having them hit `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp` and checking the results. Here is my best attempt with `wget`:

```
wgetCmd = "wget http://localhost:8080/myWebApp"
wgetResults = subprocess.check_output([wgetCmd], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in wgetResults.strip().split('\n'):
    if 'failed' in line:
    print "\nError: myWebApp is not running."
    sys.exit()
```

My thinking here is that, if the web app isn't running, `wget`'s output should always contain the word "failed" inside of it (at least, from my experience). Unfortunately, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myUser/mywebapp-mon.py", line 52, in <module>
main()
File "/home/myUser/mywebapp-mon.py", line 21, in main
wgetResults = subprocess.check_output([wgetCmd], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['wget http://localhost:8080/myWebApp']' returned non-zero exit status 4
```

Any thoughts as to what's going on here (what the error is)? Also, and more importantly, am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check url:

```
import urllib2

def check(url):
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except EnvironmentError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

To investigate what kind of an error occurred you could look at the exception instance.

Comment: Thanks @J.F. Sebastian - ultimately, your way was quicker and simpler, and it worked 'right out of the box', so to speak. Thanks agaiN!

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you try the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. It is much more user-friendly then wget or urllib. Try something like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/myWebApp')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.text
Some text of your webapp
```

**EDIT ** installation instructions http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/

Comment: Thanks @bpgergo (+1) - when I try this I get `ImportError: No module named requests`...is there a module I need to download, and if so, how do I do this and where do I install it to (this is literally one of the first Python scripts I've ever written, but I'm a fairly experienced Java developer so I can probably fumble my way to getting it to work, with the right push). Thanks again!

Comment: OK, no problem. This module is not (yet) included in the standard Python distribution (though I believe some day it will be). So, yes, you'll have to install it additionally if you want to use it. I have added a link to the installation instructions to my answer. Please also note that there is a tool that makes installing Ptyhon modules very easy. It is called PIP. You'll probably want to install Pip and you'll have no problem with any further module installation. Refer to this guide on how to install Pip. http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#using-the-installer

Comment: It may seem a little bit overkill for your current problem, but believe me, installing Pip is an 'investment' that will return much benefit if you plan to use python in the future.

Comment: I believe you 100% :-) I'll give it a try in a few hours and post back with what I find, thanks again for all your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can also build on using urllib2/requests and interact with Tomcat's manager service if it's installed. My using the [list method](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications) you can receive the following information:

```
   OK - Listed applications for virtual host localhost
   /webdav:running:0
   /examples:running:0
   /manager:running:0
   /:running:0
```